# unsafePerformIO in threaded applications does not work

Tags: multithreading, haskell, unsafe-perform-io

Below is the source of a sample program:

When I run it from ghci both printJob and printJob2 run fine and write ten lines into a text file.

But when compiled with -threaded flag, the program writes only one line.

I have ghc 7.0.3 on ArchLinux

Here's the compile command:

```
ghc -threaded -Wall -O2 -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -o testmvar testmvar.hs
```

What am I am doing wrong ? Why it does not work in threaded mode ?

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import Control.Exception (bracket)
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import System.IO (hPutStrLn, stderr)


{-# NOINLINE p #-}
p :: MVar Int
p = unsafePerformIO $ newMVar (1::Int)


{-# NOINLINE printJob #-}
printJob x = bracket (takeMVar p) (putMVar p . (+ 1))
                   (\a -> do
                       appendFile "mvarlog.txt" $ "Input: " ++ x ++ "; Counter: " ++ show a ++ "\n"
                       )


{-# NOINLINE printJob2 #-}
printJob2 = unsafePerformIO $ do
   p2 <- newEmptyMVar
   return $ (\x -> bracket (putMVar p2 True) (\_ -> takeMVar p2)
                   (\_ -> do
                       appendFile "mvarlog.txt" $ "preformed " ++ x ++ "\n"
                   ))

main = do
  forM_ [1..10]
    (\x -> forkIO $ printJob (show x))
```

EDIT: hammar pointed out that if main application exits earlier than all spawned threads, then they will be killed and suggested to add a delay at the end of main.
I did and as he predicted, it works.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here (it's possible that compiling is triggering optimizations that GHCi isn't, and those are eliminating calls to `unsafePerformIO`), but I feel like it's worth saying, once again, that `unsafePerformIO` is, as the name implies, *unsafe*, and things *will* break if you use it.  (OK, unless you're being extremely, extremely careful, but possibly then too.)

Comment: Do you get the same result if you add a delay at the end of `main`? All other threads are killed once the main thread finishes, so depending on how things get scheduled this might do nothing -- independently of any issues related to `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: @hammar You are right! I added threadDelay at the end of main and now it all works fine. Thank you!, If you put it as a separate answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: tip: for top level MVars and more, have a look at the [safe globals](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-globals-0.1.1) package!

Comment: I am on ghc 7.0.3. From the safe-globals page: This library may not work properly on GHC before 7.4, due to a GHC bug: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5558

Comment: @VagifVerdi : Interesting, but noticed that the bug you linked to is not using safe globals, but directly using such code as you are; making an `MVar` reference with `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: I am encapsulating the global variable in a closure, so it is invisible. Thus safe-globals would not be of much use to me. As most other haskellers i am against publicly accessible global variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your main thread finishes too soon, and when the main thread of a Haskell program finishes, all other threads get killed automatically. Depending on how the threads get scheduled, this might happen before any of the threads have had a chance to run at all.

A quick and dirty solution is to simply add a `threadDelay` at the end of `main`, though a more robust method would be to use a synchronization primitive like an `MVar` to signal when it's OK for the main thread to finish.

For example:

```
main = do
  vars <- forM [1..10] $ \x -> do
    done <- newEmptyMVar -- Each thread gets an MVar to signal when it's done
    forkIO $ printJob (show x) >> putMVar done ()
    return done

  -- Wait for all threads to finish before exiting
  mapM_ takeMVar vars
```

Comment: All this said, using `unsafePerformIO` is almost certainly a bad idea here.  There are ways around it for this use case.

Comment: @Louis I would love to learn if you show me alternative way to create a semaphore without leaking abstractions. Originally i had it declared in global structure and initialized in main before starting the application server and then passing it explicitly as a parameter to printJob function. But that's simply wrong from encapsulation point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Of COURSE it doesn't work.  Using unsafePerformIO always comes back to haunt you.  Structure your code to not use it.  Using it to create global variables is not a legitimate use of it.  That is what the reader monad is for.  You don't need unsafePerformIO for anything in Haskell.

It kills me when people recommend this "trick" when it is clearly broken.  It is like the blind leading the blind.  Just don't do it and you won't have problems using Haskell.  Haskell has really beautiful and elegant solutions to every problem you throw at it, but if you insist on fighting it instead of learning it then you will always keep running into bugs.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are a moron. I am using it to create a semaphore  for shared resource (printer). There's no other way to do it but to use global MVar. And here you come spewing bullshit about "evil" UnsafePerformIO. It's not evil. It's just an advanced tool. Obviously not for the likes of you.

Comment: You are correct that it requires an MVar, but you aren't correct that it requires unsafePerformIO.  There is nothing preventing you from initializing it within the body of your main function and passing the MVar reference around.  If you don't like passing the variable reference around, use the reader monad.  If you don't like to structure your code functionally at all, then why are you using Haskell?

Comment: Who says anything about requiring UnsafePerformIO ? In fact if you put it like this then even haskell itself is not required, i could just write it in java. Initializing a global variable outside of the function is ugly and wrong. You are spilling the guts all over the place. My first implementation had this MVar defined in one module, initialized in another and used in third. That breaks all encapsulation laws. And i value my encapsulation more that idiotic superstitions about UnsafePerformIO. Unsafe in that name really means "keep away from children". Engineers know how and when to use it.

Comment: What you are asking for is impurity disguised as "modularity".  Haskell requires you to pass these kinds of parameters around, either explicitly or through an implicit reader monad, in order to guarantee purity.  The compiler trusts you when you say your code is pure, but if your code is not actually pure then the compiler becomes your enemy and you are forced to do things like NOINLINE and spend substantial time dealing with concurrency bugs from code that depends on your function being pure.

Comment: The procedure in question prints out batches of files. It is obviously as impure as it can be. I am not making it more impure that it already is :) But i am making it substantially simpler to use and hiding away low level implementation details. Besides i do not even have a global variable anymore (it is hidden in the closure) so some clueless newbie programmer will not be able to break it by using the global public variable for something else, or even worse, passing to printJob function another MVar. Architecture matters.

Comment: You can hide code from a programmer, but you can't hide it from the compiler.  The time will come when the compiler will apply a code transformation that assumes your function is pure and then breaks your code.  You don't have to take my word for it, though, because despite all your bravado I know you'll come back later begging for help when your code doesn't behave the way you think it should.  Like I said before, if you don't understand the importance of purity then Haskell isn't the right language for you.

Comment: Your irrational fear of UnsafePerformIO clouds your mind. The only result of its application is that this code will be performed once and memoized. That's EXACTLY what i want from it. Why on earth haskell would TRANSFORM something it already computed and stored ? Tha would break not only my code but EVERYONE ELSE's code :) if you don't understand the applications and implications of purity then Haskell isn't the right language for you.

Comment: Bro really came out here to fight lmao. Imagine having a bug in your code and telling the person who took time out of their day to give an answer that they're a moron. If she's a moron then what does that make you fam?